# Uma aplicação para vários clientes com Laravel

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel

Estou criando um projeto de uma aplicação web para vários clientes usando o **Laravel**. No meu projeto essa aplicação teria vários bancos de dados,sendo um para cada cliente. Pesquisando na internet, vi que isso com o passa do tempo seria complicado de se manter, por várias questões como: manutenção, backups e etc... considerando isso seria melhor criar uma aplicação com banco de dados único e relacionando essas tabelas? Nosso maior medo é haver uma mistura desses dados na aplicação. Alguém poderia nos dá uma luz...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você vai manter as mesmas tabelas para os clientes, ou uma mesma base, não tem porque fazer isso. Basta fazer um relacionamento 1 para 1 em cada tabela com uma tabela de usuários que os dados não se misturariam (é premissa do banco de dados não permitir isso, mas claro que ele precisa da colaboração do programador), uma vez que cada dado pertence a um único cliente.

Dá uma estudada no relacionamento 1 para 1 nos bancos de dados tal como o Laravel trabalha com eles através do seguinte link: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

[edit] Não tinha lido a outra resposta quando iniciei essa, mas é exatamente o que ele diz, uma resposta complementa a outra. ;)

Comment: Verdade Gabriel Tadra. Estou pesquisando aqui. Obrigado!

Comment: Favor escolher uma resposta como certa! Obrigado! :)

Answer (score 4):

Para sua solução você poderia pesquisar sobre arquitetura multi-tenancy.

Andei procurando sobre multi-tenancy em Laravel e infelizmente não achei muita coisa (pré-pronta).

Basicamente você cria uma tabela de Tenancy (locatários ou utilizador, por exemplo) e em TODAS as tabelas você fixa quem é o dono daquele dado.

Em toda consulta você terá que adicionar o tenant_id do usuário logado.

Não achei nenhum link interessante no stack overflow em português, então vou deixar este link do iMasters para você http://imasters.com.br/artigo/19067/cloud/entendendo-o-modelo-multi-tenancy/.

**@edit** o modelo que você procura se chama SaaS (Software as a Service).

Comment: Obrigado Por responder Willian, estou pesquisando o indicado.

Comment: Galera da negativo e não comenta kkkkk, engraçado demais.